# NHibernate: Add entity to many-to-many collection by id only

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm looking for a shortcut. I have some NH entities with a many-to-many relationship. Something like this:

```
public class Customer : EntityBase<Customer>
{
    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category : EntityBase<Category>
{
    public virtual IList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Bear in mind this is a very simple depiction, so resist the temptation to suggest I not use a many-to-many arrangement or that I should use a value type or anything like that.

On the DB side, this relationship is accomplished via a separate table with two columns - `Customer_Id` and `Category_Id`.

I'd really like to be able to add an existing `Category` to a `Customer` without having to retrieve the full entity from the database. Maybe something like this:

```
customerEntity.Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 2 });
```

The reason for this is that the application is an ASP.NET MVC app and I'm using ViewModels for my views. These `Customer` ViewModels end up with a `List<int>` for the category selections, and when I go to map that ViewModel to the corresponding `Customer` entity, I'd love to just be able to suck those category IDs into the `Categories` list without having to hit the database to retrieve them first.

Part of the reason I want to be able to do this is that I'd like to minimize database calls, but I also would like to have my mapper class be able to create the `Customer` entity without having to make calls to my service layer to go asking for other objects...that seems like bad design. I'd also like to avoid having to add another layer to call the mapper then do the other mapping stuff that pulls entities from the repository (which is itself accessed through a domain service layer).

I checked out `idbag`, but for one I'm using Fluent NHibernate and it doesn't support that construct, and for two from what I can glean from the docs that will give me a `List<int>` on the entity, and I'd still like to be able to access the full entity in those collections.

Am I asking too much out of NHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ISession.Load](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id):

```
customerEntity.Categories.Add(session.Load<Category>(2));
```

Load will return a proxy and does not hit the database. You can access the ID property of the proxy without hitting the database, but NHibernate will load the proxy if you access any other properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, my session isn't directly exposed to the ASP.NET MVC app. I'd have to make a call to a repository in another library. I was hoping to have to have my ViewModel mapper have to talk directly to the repository layer. Any way around that?

Comment: Well, let me correct myself - I don't generally access the session from the MVC app.